# Употребление "и/или"

Tags: союзы

В работе возникла спорная ситуация. Зачастую в нормативных актах используется следующая конструкция "Депозитарная деятельность - оказание услуг по хранению сертификатов ценных бумаг и / или учету и переходу прав на ценные бумаги", "который должен состоять из цифр и (или) букв латинского алфавита".

Вопрос в следующем: подобное использование союзов и/или допускает два или три варианта прочтения? Какие это варианты?

В моем представлении допускается три варианта, например:

1. состоять из цифр и букв,
2. состоять из цифр,
3. состоять из букв.

Гос.органы понимают это как два варианта:

1. состоять из цифр и букв,
2. состоять из цифр.

Т.е. союз или применяется не к частям предложения, между которыми он стоит, а к варианты с союзом "и" как целому и к первому варианту до союза.

Comment: Роди мне мальчика и/или девочку. <=> Либо роди мне мальчика, но не девочку; либо роди мне девочку, но не мальчика; либо роди мне и мальчика, и девочку.

Подари мне дом и/или яхту. <=> Либо подари мне дом, но не яхту; либо подари мне яхту, но не дом; либо подари мне и дом, и яхту.

Comment: Иван любит Дарью и/или Марью. <=> Либо Иван любит Дарью, но не любит Марью; либо Иван любит Марью, но не любит Дарью; либо Иван любит и Дарью, и  Марью.

Answer (score 1):

Всякий, кто знаком с формальной логикой или теорией множеств (булевой алгеброй), найдёт в такой записи -- "и/или" -- ЕДИНСТВЕННЫЙ вариант, а именно "теоретико-множественное объединение" (ТМО), логическое "ИЛИ".

Это очередной пример, когда в языке требуется выразить некую "формулу" и срочно подыскиваются языковые средства, для этого особо не предназначенные.

Что же такое ТМО? это совокупность элементов из двух или более объединяемых множеств.
В нашем случае имеются множество букв и множество цифр. Если сгребём их в одну кучу, то получим множество, включающее как буквы, так и цифры. Вот здесь она, эта формула (= ТМО)! Обозначается  [image] , читается "A или B". Фраза "из цифр и/или букв" означает: из элементов множества [image]. Математически ровно одно прочтение (а не два, не три).

Вопрос №1: откуда большее число прочтений? тут работает бытовая логика: если из одних букв, то это для нас одно, если из одних цифр - это другое, если они вперемешку, это третье. Математик же видит за текстом точную формулу, объединяющую все три прочтения.

Вопрос №2: почему тут и "и", и "или"? Снова разница между нашим обыденным языком и языком математики. Математик говорит "или" и понимает под этим: "каждый элемент принадлежит или множеству A, или множеству B (или обоим, кстати!)".

В быту мы говорим "и":  "буквы и цифры", имея в виду ТО ЖЕ САМОЕ. Как это возможно? Здесь играет роль грамматическое множественное число, к-рое есть в русском и к-рого нет у математиков.

Вот так, таинственным образом, "или" превращается в "и"; и наоборот. Разделительный союз в математике не разделяет, а соединяет :-)

Никого не собираясь запутать, добавлю, что к математиков есть и логическое "И", "теоретико-множественное пересечение" (ТМП). Обозначается A & B, а тж [image]. Читается "A и B", включает только такие элементы, к-рые входят как в A, так и в B. Если взять ТМП множества букв и множества цифр, то мы не получим ни одного элемента! Т.е. получим "пустое множество" -- ведь ни одна буква не является одновременно цифрой...

Напоследок вопрос: а какие средства языка используются для того, чтобы выразить эту, вторую формулу (т.е. ТМП)?

Comment: для полноты картины: ТМО называется тж дизъюнкцией, а ТМП -- конъюнкцией.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь возможны 3 варианта прочтения, которые вы указали.

Выдержка из Полного академического справочника.

Косая черта

§ 114. Сфера применения знака / (косая черта) — научная и деловая речь. Он употребляется в следующих функциях.

1.**В функции, близкой к союзам *и* и *или***, как знак альтернативности понятий или обозначения единого сложного понятия, напр.: категория одушевлённости/неодушевлённости, проблема слитных/раздельных написаний (в лингвистических текстах); Погребения датируются новым/новейшим временем (из археологической статьи); обязательство покупки/продажи ценных бумаг по объявленным ценам; Развивающий тренажёр «прыгунки» регулируется на размер/вес малыша (из газет).

В этой функции может употребляться не только косая черта, но и дефис.

2.**Для обозначения отношения каких-либо величин, параметров** (в том числе в математическом смысле), напр.: По параметрам — цена/качество, удобство в работе, простота в обращении — модель заняла лидирующее положение в своём классе множительной техники; Компьютер занял 4-е место по количеству набранных баллов и 2-е по отношению баллы/цена; Курс доллар/евро опустился до минимального значения за последние две недели; Новый ризограф с разрешающей способностью 600 точек/дюйм (из газет).
В той же функции употребляется косая черта в сокращенных обозначениях составных единиц измерения, напр.: ц/га (центнер на гектар), об/мин (оборот в минуту).

НИКАКОГО ОСНОВАНИЯ ДЛЯ УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЯ В ОДНОЙ ЧАСТИ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ СЛЕША, А В ДРУГОЙ СКОБОК НЕТ.

То есть слеш читается так: услуг по хранению сертификатов ценных бумаг и/или учету и переходу прав на ценные бумаги = хранению и учету; хранению или учету. Тот же смысл передает и *и (или)*.

Comment: Тогда не пойму, чем руководствуются, когда читают два варианта

Comment: Мне тоже интересно, чем они руководствуются. 2 варианта выглядели бы так: состоять из цифр и букв или букв латинского алфавита. Если хотели сократить, то сделали это безграмотно.

Comment: Слеш раньше использовался в формулах и условных обозначениях, в других случаях использовали скобки. Недавно слеш был признан небуквенным орфографическим знаком, но никакого нового значения, отличного от скобок, у него не появилось.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае союз "и"  является соединительным  и имеет значение " и это, и то",союз "или" является разделительным и имеет значение " или это, или то". Следовательно, как вы правильно отметили , здесь допускается три варианта: 1. 1. состоять из цифр и букв, 2 состоять из цифр, 3.состоять из букв.

Дополнение к сказанному,читайте здесь:  [Русская корпусная грамматика](http://rusgram.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#511)

А вот и ответ Граммы.ру:

> <<Нам неизвестно, проводил ли кто-либо специальные корпусные исследования с целью установить возможные значения и/или. Мы можем опереться лишь на функции знака слеш, или косая вертикальная черта. Как сообщает "Школьный энциклопедический словарь "Русский язык" (СПб., 2013), в котором впервые появилась подробное описание этого неалфавитного знака, функция слеша состоит в том, чтобы "соединять однородные компоненты, находящиеся в синтаксическом противопоставлении, и указывать на альтернативность понятий: проблема слитных/раздельных написаний (в значении союза как…, так и…);  в режиме замены/вставки (в значении союза  либо…, либо…); различия в пунктуации однородных/неоднородных определений (в значении с одной стороны…, с другой стороны…)>>.

Comment: тут встречается такая трактовка: союз и соединяет - один вариант, а союз или предполагает наличие второго варианта "буквы", т.е если раскрыть предложение, получается "цифры и буквы или буквы". Не могу понять, чем руководствуются...

Answer (score 0):

Если государственные органы понимают запись И(ИЛИ)  как два варианта: 1. состоять из цифр и букв, 2. состоять из цифр, то так оно и есть.  Думаю, что заявления о безграмотности оформлении совершенны неуместны, но обозначение И(ИЛИ)  надо расшифровать.

Если там действительно два варианта, то запись  И (ИЛИ) понимается именно так: из цифр или из цифр и букв.

Имеются в виду, что соединительный союз И имеет метку ИЛИ: а) без союза И (только из цифр); б) с союзом И (из цифр и букв).

Answer (score 0):

"Справка" (см.Серж) права в том, что никакой реальной фиксации значения слежа как письменного знака нет. Но неправа в том, что это что-то значит. К сожалению, ни в официальные, ни юридические, ни даже математические тексты не свободны от необходимости привлекать контекст для их понимания. Это в полной мере касается и слежа. Чтобы ссылаться на понимание неких госооганов необходимо представить полностью документ (а не одну фразу), официальный ответ органа, мотивацию и вообще ситуацию в целом. Спорить же можно только имея на руках лингвистическую экспертизу.

Конкретно понимание конструкций "и/или" и "и (или)" будет зависеть, в частности, от используемого глагола. Скажем, "пароли могут быть из букв и/или цифр" и "пароли должны быть из букв и/или цифр" могут трактоваться по-разному.

Если же не подниматься до уровня "госорганов", то совершенно непонятно из чего исходят авторы вашей трактовки. Если присмотреться, все формулировки "симметричны" относительно букв и цифр. И епе это модет породить несимметричную трактовку (буквы допускаются, а цифры - нет) совершенно непонятно.

> "который должен состоять из цифр и (или) букв латинского алфавита".

Здесь я вижу сокращенную запись следующего. 
Некий объект должен удовлетворять следующим требования.

a)  он должен состоять из букв и цифр
б)  он должен состоять из букв или цифр.

По-другому тут понять невозможно.

Возникает вопрос, в каких отношениях состоят а) и б), т.е. должны ли эти условия выполняться одновременно? Понятно, что одновременно эти условия выполняться не могут. Значит, де-факто имеется в виду, допускается любой из вариантов. А это эквивалентно тому, что все три варианта допустимы.

***Вообще же запись "и/или" придумана для того, чтобы обозначить так называемое "неисключающее или".  Запись "я и/или он" означает "или я, или он, или мы оба" (в то время как "я или он" оставляет некоторую двусмысленность)***. Я не вижу причин отказываться от такой трактовки. Но у "госорганов", конечно, могут быть свои резоны, но хотялось бы их услышать.

Добавлю для математиков. Сабельный поход с теорией множеств наперевес тут не проходит. Дело в том, что фразы типа "множество желтых и круглых объектов" может пониматься по-разному математиками и обывателями". Математик (условный) включит в него все объекты, ***которые желтые и круглые***. А простой смертный (тоже условный) - ***те, которые желтые, и те, которые круглые***. И кто более прав, я рискну утверждать.

Answer (score 0):

Очень путанная формулировка, хотя и сам вопрос не очень понятный. Что за госорганы, кто вообще подобные инструкции пишет?

Я согласна с тем, что понимаете тут определяется в основном контекстом, а вне контекста да, самое правильное считать возможным все три варианта.

И с тем, что без стакана (экспертизы) тут трудно что-либо сказать по существу.

По опыту же полагаю, что с хозяевами жизни лучше не связываться. Как скажут, так и понимайте. По возможности старайтесь получить это понимание письменно. А то ведь завтра они будут понимать всё по-другому.

По поводу самого знака. Мне непонятна апелляция "Граммы" (см. пост Сержа) к необходимости каких-то исследований. Речь ведь идет не о слеже (слеше?) вообще, а ио вполне известной конструкции "и/или". В ней косая черта означает именно "или". "Бумаги лежат на или в столе" - не совсем по-русски, но понятно.

Аналогично, *"должен состоять из цифр и/или букв латинского алфавита"* означало бы, что допустимы две возможности.
a) Состоит из букв и цифр
b) Состоит из букв или цифр

Всего, таким образом, можно насчитать и три варианта, о которых говорилось в вопросе.